# C# / Unity: Multiply BigInteger by Float

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, biginteger, bigint

I have a BigInteger cost = 111111222222333333444444555555 and a float costMultiply 1.1f.

I try to:

```
newCost = cost * costMultiply
```

And get an "Operator "*" cannot be applied"- Error.

I also tried:

```
int multiplierBuffer = (int)(costMultiply * 10);
cost = cost * (multiplierBuffer / 10);
```

This does not throw an error but gives back the initial cost value (not multiplied by 1.1f).

How do I multiply my BigInteger by a float?

Comment: Multiply by 11 and divide by 10

Comment: costMultiply is a variable that is not always 1.1f. It may have different decimals eventually, so I need a solution using a float variable and not hard-coded values.

Comment: What type do you expect the result to be in? You have 30 digits of precision there. Do you need them all? If so, you are stuck with BigInteger (floats give you 6-9 digits, doubles 15-17 and decimals 28-29, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types). Write some code that translates a float into a multiply and a divide by a power of 10 (hint, use a logarithm), and do it that way.

Comment: I expect the result to be another BigInteger. No BigInteger will ever be larger than 30 digits in my program. What do you mean by "translates a float into a multiply and a divide"?

Comment: If the multiplier is, for example, `2.25f`, figure out that there are two digits after the decimal point (the easiest way might be to have a loop, on each iteration, multiply by 10 and check to make sure that the number, when rounded to an int is *close enough*). In your case 22.5 isn't close to 22, but 225 works). So your multiplier is 225 and your divisor is 100. I'd write this out as and answer, but I'm on my phone

Comment: You can't multiply a BigInteger by a float or a double. You have to do something else, like cast the BigInteger to a double. Perhaps you want the decimal type instead?

Comment: Can you follow LWun's advice but make it dynamic? Like "cost = cost * (int)(costMultiply*1000); cost = cost/1000;" ?

Comment: Every floating-point number is actually a rational number, where the denominator is a power of 2.  So the operation can be done, exactly (the floating-point value may have lost some precision previously, but we won't lose any more in the multiply) but it probably was kept out of the API because the slow performance would be surprising (comparable to division not multiplication)

Comment: BigIntegers subcomponents have place values which are binary, not decimal.  So while @Flydog57 had a valid idea, powers of 10 and logarithms will accomplish nothing but slowing the operation. Ivan's suggestion should have used 1024 instead of 1000, so the division becomes a bit-shift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to cast your BigInteger to a double/Double.

```
    BigInteger cost = new BigInteger(10000000000000000000);
    float costMultiply = 1.1f;
    double dCost = (double) cost;
    double result = dCost * costMultiply;
    // And since you want a BigInteger at the end
    BigInteger bigIntResult = new BigInteger(result);
```

The actual type of `result` would be `Double` because the integer can't fit into a `double`. C# takes care of that for you.

This can obviously be simplified.

```
    BigInteger cost = new BigInteger(10000000000000000000);
    float costMultiply = 1.1f;
    BigInteger bigIntResult = new BigInteger((double) cost * costMultiply);
```

The thing is, your mathematics is going to be a screwy because of the varying levels of precision in the data types.  I wouldn't use this approach if you need precision.  However, since you want to multiply an integer by a floating point number and get an integer result, I guess you won't be bothered by precision issues.

Comment: This will erase a potentially very large amount of data. Let's say the BigInteger has 2000 significant digit, this would only keep the 16 most significant ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
BigInteger cost = BigInteger.Parse("111111222222333333444444555555");
        BigInteger costMultiply = (BigInteger)(1.1f*1000f);
        BigInteger result = cost * costMultiply / 1000;
```

Result:122222344444566666788889011110

A little late, but I was also looking and this works best for me

Comment: This order is faster but much less precise.  Doing multiply before division will reduce your error by a factor of about 1100.

Comment: Indeed, the multiplication order is wrong. You want `cost * BigInteger(N) / BigInteger(doubleMultiplier * N)` N being a very large integer stored in a double, such as 2^32. This will ensure all significant digits of the float multiplier are kept intact.